# Scala - Create user-type with method

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have a generic class which takes one type, and I have a parameter from that type. The issue is that I need to use a method from this parameter (in my problem, I need to use the method getTimestamp).
I can't have a trait or an abstract class because I know that, at some point, the type will be a Java Class that I can't modified.

I tried something like this :

```
type InputWithTimestamp = {def getTimestamp: Long}

class Foo[Input <: InputWithTimestamp](f : Input) {
   def printTimestamp = { println(f.getTimestamp) }
}

class Test(timestamp : Long) {
  def getTimestamp = timestamp
}

val t = new Test(1000)

val f = new Foo(t)
f.printTimestamp
```

And it is perfectly working.

But as I said, at some point I need to use a java class as a type.

And here is my problem :

Even if the java class defined a method getTimestamp which returns a long, I have the following error :

```
Error: inferred type arguments [MyJavaClass] do not conform to class Foo's type parameter bounds [Input <: InputWithTimestamp]
```

So what can I do to have a generic type which defined this method without needing to modify my java class ?

Comment: What does `MyJavaClass` look like, especially, how is its `getTimestamp` method defined? Beware that `Long` by default is `scala.Long`, which is not `java.lang.Long`, so if the Java class returns `java.lang.Long` then it's a mismatch.

Comment: This is what I thought but I tested by changing and the problem doesn't come from there.
But I just found the solution, I just need to add parentheses in `type InputWithTimestamp = {def getTimestamp(): Long}` and it's working

Comment: You can post that as an anwer to your own question - there's nothing wrong with [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It might be useful for people who find this question and answer in the future.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a wrapper (may be implicit conversion if neccessary) for your java class, that impl. an Trait that offers getTimestamp. This solution does nocht use reflective calls, which are ugly, slow and lead to problems, as just shown by your.

Comment: I can't really explain why but I'm my case I can't do that. 
To be short, I need to implement some code so the client just have to use small amount of code to do big things. I can't ask him to wrap the class. I could do it my self for this class, but i don't know if he'll need an another class in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I didn't use parentheses to declare my method `getTimestamp` (because you get a warning in IDEA if you do so).

But in that case, I need the parentheses, otherwise the java method `getTimestamp`  doesn't match the scala method

```
type InputWithTimestamp = {def getTimestamp: Long}
```

works perfectly.